# What characters should be replaced to avoid HTML being output?

Tags: php, html, escaping

I have some user input in a website, and **I don't want to allow HTML** when outputting that input with PHP later.

I think that the only dangerous characters are `<`, `>`, `/`(slash) and `\` (backslash).

Am I right?

So, for example, if I replace `<` with `&#60;` will it be enough to prevent HTML being output?

Comment: @PeeHaa I added it because the question says "when echoing that input by php later".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use the builtin function [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and you will be good. Just note that you should also always add the encoding argument.

And example is:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($unsafeString, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: For a certain reason I can't use it for all purposes because the &(ampersand) is also "destroyed" by htmlspecialchars(). But mostly this function will work for you.